# Flex error skin incorrectly drawing

Tags: apache-flex, validation, flex4, skin

I really hope there is someone that can help me out on this one. It took me days to implement a decent looking error skin for some custom text inputs but I am running into what seems to be a measuring issue with the resulting bitmap from validating.

I duplicated the Flex default error skin into my own class and just adjusted the GlowFilter to be "inner" and some color changes.

Setting the focus skin to NULL was an attempt to remove that styling since validation turns that thing red and applies it on top of everything else.

```
<view:PromptedTextInput id="inputCompanyName"
                    width="100%" height="35"
                    focusSkin="{null}"
                    styleName="promptedTextInput"
                    errorSkin="com.verical.common.skins.InnerGlowErrorSkin"
                    prompt="company name (optional)"
                    skinClass="com.verical.checkout.view.skins.PromptedUserInputSkin" />
```

Here is what I sometimes see happen randomly.

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, I am also noticing that processBitmap() is firing twice